# create code to give change based on user input

Tags: ruby

I am stumped by an assignment. I must write code to create a virtual candy machine which will greet the user, list all candy choices, confirm amount of money/candy choice user inputs and give out change and candy as needed. I find myself unable to create code to get the machine to confirm candy selection and give out change. Basically I am trying to create code that will be responsive to user needs. Please help. Here is the code I have so far:

```
puts "hello"
puts "welcome to candy machine"
puts candy = Array["A - oreo", "B - twix", "C - chips", "D - gum"]
Candy = Hash["oreo" => 1 "twix" => 2, "chips" => 3, "gum" => 4]
puts "would you like to order? Select 1, 2, 3, 4
user_input = gets.chomp
price = Array[1.20, 1.25, 1.00, 0.50]
puts "You selected:"
puts "#{Candy[user_input]}"
puts "please pay", "#{price[user_input]}"
```

Comment: What's the error you're getting when trying to run the code? From a cursory glance it seems as if there are a few syntax issues (missing comma in hash upon assigning `Candy`, missing closing string `"` on the following line). Apart from that it appears you're trying to get the value of candy selected by index, so converting the user input to an integer and offsetting by -1 should help (`gets.chomp.to_i` and `price[user_input - 1]`).

Answer (score 0):

I think as a comment mentions, you have a lot of errors, but I think they are from typing up on SO.

The issue is you're using a hash, with string keys - the words for each candy, but ask for an index.  Reverse your hash and it should work.

I.e. change this:

```
candy = Hash["oreo" => 1 "twix" => 2, "chips" => 3, "gum" => 4]
```

to:

```
candy = [1 => 'oreo', 2 => 'twix', 3 => 'chips', 4 => 'gum']
```

And the same with prices array